# Visual Studio & C#: Finding conflicting definitions contained in namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

Every now and then I run into the error
 `The namespace 'My.SuperAwesome.Namespace' already contains a definition for 'SomeClass'`

Which is fine, I understand namespaces and that I have conflicting class definitions. The problem is, how do I find that conflicting definition?

Comment: Just write `SomeClass class` and move your mouse on the SomeClass, it will tell you the class' namespace, which can be `My.SuperAwesome.Namespace.Specific.Classes.SomeClass` so if your application is well organized, you'll find it easily. You can also right click on `SomeClass` and go to the definition. (or F12)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here - is it to be able to locate the source file/assembly that also contains a definition for `SomeClass`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes

Answer (score 2):

I would temporarily rename the new class with some other name, then add a `SomeClass` member to it, then right-click and choose "Go to Definition", which should take you to the other definition.

So, change:

```
namespace My.SuperAwesome.Namespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {

    }
}
```

To:

```
namespace My.SuperAwesome.Namespace
{
    class NotSomeClass
    {
       SomeClass foo;
    }
}
```

And go to definition on `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the Class view window which shows you a hierarchical view of your namespaces and their members.

[image: Class view window]

If you double click some class, it will show you all the definitions and where they are.

[image: Viewing class definitions]